# Sitecore license

Tags: installation

I've just started working on a Sitecore based project from last month. To learn and practice more about various concepts of Sitecore I want to install in my personal laptop. How can I get Sitecore license for learning and practicing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to use the license of a client or partner who has one. It does make it hard to get started in Sitecore.

Previously Sitecore launched a 60 days trial license, I am not confirmed right now this is available or not. You can get more information from below link.

https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/blog/359/getting-started-as-a-developer-4499