# Sitecore 10 Developer License

Tags: license

I am  inquiring about the availability of a trial version for Sitecore 10 version, typically offered for a limited period, such as 60 days, for developers to explore the platform's capabilities.

For information regarding license fees, especially for a team of two developers, I visited the official Sitecore website. However I didn't get enough insights about the licensing options which can help me to get started.

Any help will be greatly appreciable about license and pricing model.

Comment: Check this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31812/sitecore-license/31813#31813